# The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

> CUDA Version: 10.0   tensorflow 2.0.0-alpha0
>  jupyter notebook
>   
>  python 3.5.6 
>  cuda toolkit 10.0 
>  ubuntu 18.10
>
> define CUDNN_MAJOR 7 
>  define CUDNN_MINOR 5 
>  define
>   CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 1 
>  define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 +
>   CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL) include "driver_types.h"

The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. 
strange thing is cudnn version I installed is 7.5.1. 
 But error message is keep saying that Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.3.1 but source was compiled with: 7.4.2. CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. I have no idea why 7.3.1 cudnn library came from.

This message come out after I installed '2.0.0-alpha0' tensorflow.

> name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582 pciBusID:
>   0000:42:00.0 totalMemory: 11.90GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB 2019-05-14
>   08:03:49.028136: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1546] Adding visible
>   gpu devices: 0 2019-05-14 08:03:49.028424: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0 2019-05-14
>   08:03:49.029904: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1015] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-05-14
>   08:03:49.029928: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1021]      0 
>   2019-05-14 08:03:49.029938: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1034] 0:   N 
>   2019-05-14 08:03:49.030490: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1149] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
>   10796 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus
>   id: 0000:42:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 2019-05-14 08:03:57.812557:
>   I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0 2019-05-14
>   08:03:58.069834: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7 2019-05-14
>   08:03:58.730756: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328]
>   Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.3.1 but source was compiled with:
>   7.4.2.  CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a
>   binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources,
>   make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version
>   specified during compile configuration. 2019-05-14 08:03:58.732680: E
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328] Loaded runtime CuDNN
>   library: 7.3.1 but source was compiled with: 7.4.2.  CuDNN library
>   major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in
>   case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade
>   your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library
>   loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during
>   compile configuration. 2019-05-14 08:03:58.733465: F
>   tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_input_ops.cc:955] Check failed:
>   stream->parent()->GetConvolveBackwardDataAlgorithms(
>   conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(stream->parent()),
>   &algorithms)

This is the main message when kernel died

question: jupyter notebook restart with kernel died. with above message. 
Need to fix it.

Comment: And, what is your question?

Comment: jjupyter notebook restart with kernel died. with above message. Need to fix it.

Comment: depending on how you installed any of the these things, you may (evidently) have multiple versions of CUDNN installed, and its also evident that your tensorflow is using the wrong version.  You should probably fix that.

Comment: how to check multiple version installed.